# Run console program targeted by a .lnk from another shell (Powershell Core)?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, file-shortcut

I have a folder of `.lnk` shortcuts to CLI apps in different folders. The shortcut folder is added to `PATH`, and my `PATHEXT` contains the ".lnk" extension. As a result, I can just type `ffplay` in my shell, and Windows automatically finds the `D:/shortcuts/ffplay.lnk` file and runs the `ffplay.exe` executable it points to.

When I run `ffplay` from cmd, it works as expected, outputs usage help to my terminal and exits. When I do the same from Powershell (it does not matter if it is the old `powershell.exe` or new `pwsh.exe`), there is no stdout output, and a new conhost window with the output appears instead.

Is it possible to make the linked commands behave as normal console program executables do?

How to reproduce:

1. Create a `.lnk` shortcut to a native command, for example to `C:/Windows/System32/PING.EXE`, with a different name, so you can run it (so, maybe `D:/shortcuts/lnkping.lnk`).
2. Open `cmd.exe`, cd to shortcut directory, run `.\lnkping.lnk 1.1.1.1`, output is inline as normal.

   *ex. CMD Output*

   [image: CMD Link Output - Windows 10 - Screenshot]
3. Open `powershell.exe`, cd to shortcut directory, run `.\lnkping 1.1.1.1` - invocation immediately returns, new conhost window is open and output is displayed there.

   [image: PowerShell CMD/Link Output - Windows 10 - Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to make the linked commands behave as normal console program executables do?

The solution to this issue may be not to use `.lnk` files, but to use `.bat` files instead e.g.:

*ex. lnkping.bat*

```
@Echo Off
C:\Windows\System32\ping.exe %*
```

`%*` allows the `.bat` file to accept any number of additional parameters, which are then passed to the specified executable as if they were typed directly at the command line. And much like `.lnk` files, under normal circumstances the `.bat` extension does not need to be included when the "script" is invoked (so e.g. `.\lnkping 1.1.1.1` should work without issue).

Comment: Surprisingly, using `.cmd`/`.bat` is about 70ms faster than .lnk files, I expected the opposite. Shortcuts are nice, as they follow their target when it's moved, but .cmd seem fine for my usecase (before running the command, I `cd /d` to parent directory, otherwise dependencies are broken). I also tried symlinks, which work well if the program does not have any dependencies in its installation folder.

Comment: Indeed. While `.lnk` files do have certain advantages, the `.bat` and symlink options are the ones I have personally found to be most useful.